# executeTransactionAsync doesn't refresh data after onSuccess call

Tags: java, android, realm

First, previous answers to similar questions on SO didn't helped me at all.

Sometimes when calling `executeTransactionAsync()` I don't get refreshed data on UI thread in `onSuccess` method.

For example, in the following snippet I have a part of the callback instance that should store received data to Realm. This callback instance is created in the UI thread (of course):

```
@Override
public void onResponse(final Response<TicketAddItemResult> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (!isSuccess()) {
        return;
    }
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    if (realm.isClosed()) return;

    try {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                RealmTicketsHandler.updateCurrentTicket(realm, response.body().result);
                //!!!! Underneath log sometimes from here shows different result than the log in onSuccess with the same query
                Log.d(TAG, "execute: (thread) size = " + RealmTicketsHandler.getCurrentTicket(realm).getTicketItems().size() );
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "execute: (onSuccess) size = " + RealmTicketsHandler.getCurrentTicket(realm).getTicketItems().size() );
                } finally {
                    realm.close();
                }
                postEvent(new TicketRefreshed());
            }
        });
    } finally {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

In the method `RealmTicketsHandler.updateCurrentTicket(realm, data)` I just get object (`Ticket`) from realm, create new object (`TicketItem`) which will be added to `RealmList<TicketItem>` and that's it.

Nevertheless, after updating Realm in background thread, log from `execute()` method of `Realm.Transaction` object shows me that everything is added correctly, but in the `OnSuccess()` method of `Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess` instance, log sometimes doesn't show expected result.

Object of `TicketItem` doesn't have any references to `Ticket`.

Could someone explain me why is this happening?

***Realm version:*** **4.2.0**, but the same behaviour can be experienced in **4.1.1**

**NOTE:** opening Realm in `onSuccess` is done just to directly show if the data is refreshed in the current thread.

**NOTE 2:** I also have some background threads without loopers that use realm, but they act as they should and data is quickly refreshed on the UI thread.

Comment: Maybe the problem is you close the `Realm` instance before the asynchronous transaction does a callback to onSuccess/onError?

Comment: I don't think so, because this realm instance is already "opened" in UI thread and closing here just decrements the internal counter of "opened" connections in this thread..

Comment: That should be impossible, so I'll just sit on the side and wait for answers.

Comment: I also have in my app some background threads without loopers. Maybe that's the thing. I'll edit question with that fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be an expected behavior, `onSuccess()` will guarantee two things:

1. The transaction has been executed.
2. The data was changed in the transaction has been included in the current DB version on **the thread** where the asycn transaction started **when the `onSuccess()` is called**.

The below case may help you to understand why you see different logs in the transaction block and `onSuccess()`.

1. UI thread calls `executeTransactionAsync()` to change the data to version `1`.
2. The background thread executes the transaction, and now the DB on the background thread has data version `1`.
3. Another thread executes a transaction and changes the data to version `2`.
4. The UI thread received the DB update event and gets the data changes both in step `2` and `3`. `onSuccess()` is called, and you are not only seeing the changes in step 2, but also together with data changes in step 3. So you may see the data version 3 in the `onSuccess()` callback.

Be noticed that, `onSuccess()` only guarantees that you will have the data changed in the async transaction, but it won't and cannot (well, due to concurrency is hard to guarantee this) guarantee you only see the data changes in the corresponding async transaction. The data changed later could also be seen in the `onSuccess()`.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. But how can I know when I am having the right value? If on step 2 and on step 3 threads change different object, why I don't see change in step 3 then?

Comment: I am talking about getting changes in onSuccess, of course.

Comment: if `onSuccess()` gets delivered before the step 3, you won't see the changes in step 3. Does this explain?

Comment: So, actually you are saying that if in my `executeTransactionAsync`'s `onSuccess` method in UI thread, I am not 100% sure that I will have changes made in `execute` method of `Realm.Transaction`? Right now, I don't care about changes in other background transactions.

Comment: no, I am saying if you call `executeTransactionAsync()`, and when the `onSuccess()` called on UI thread, it is guaranteed you will see changes you made in the transaction block, but it could also include changes made by other thread(or another `executeTransactionAsync()` called on UI thread in between.).

Comment: but if you didn't see the changes in the corresponding transaction, then it is a bug in Realm side.